# How to force dynamically loaded MVC controllers to take particular MasterName

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Consider we have some compiled class libraries which contain some Controllers and relevant Views, that called Plugins.
in other side we have an web MVC application which loads plugins at run-time and renders existing embedded views and controllers by `WindsorControllerFactory`.

```
 [Transient]
/// <summary>
/// Controller Factory class for instantiating controllers using the Windsor IoC container.
/// </summary>
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IWindsorContainer _container;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="WindsorControllerFactory"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The Windsor container instance to use when creating controllers.</param>
    public WindsorControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found or it does not implement IController.", context.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }

        return (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        var disposable = controller as IDisposable;

        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }

        _container.Release(controller);
    }
}
```

my problem is that when I call an action from a plugin it renders page without setting `Layout` and it's empty!

i want to set Layout some constant value for every views of actions in my plugins. for example `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"`.

**Notice1** that the `_ViewStart.cshtml` fire up by every action call views in main MVC application, but it does not from calls in plugins.

**Notice2** that i don't want to set layout on the plugin side, 
neither specify MasterName on calling plugins controller's view `(return View(model,"SomeMasterName"))`, nor specifying Layout in plugin's Views such as :

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyPluginLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be set inside your VirtualPathProvider which serves embedded Views. Your `VirtualPathProvider` offers a `VirtualFile` through `GetFile(string virtualPath)` method.

```
public VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
{
    return this.IsEmbeddedFile(virtualPath) // this one you should handle by yourself
            ? new EmbeddedVirtualFile(new FileInfo(virtualPath), virtualPath) 
            : null;
}
```

A possible implementation for  your VirtualFile can be as follows:

```
public class EmbeddedVirtualFile : VirtualFile
{
    private string LayoutPath = "~/...yourpath to the Layout"
    private readonly string _virtualPath;

    public EmbeddedVirtualFile(string virtualPath) : base(virtualPath)
    {
        this._virtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public override Stream Open()
    {
        var stream = File.Open(this.fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open);
        if (_virtualPath.EndsWith(".cshtml"))
        {
            var streamFixed = CorrectView(_virtualPath, stream);
            return streamFixed;
        }
        return stream;
    }

    private Stream CorrectView(string virtualPath, Stream stream)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        var view = reader.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Close();
        var ourStream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(ourStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        // Here you may add some @usings like writer.WriteLine("@using System.Web.Mvc");
        // partial views should not have a layout & viewStart/_Layout either
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LayoutPath) && !virtualPath.Contains("/_") && !virtualPath.Contains("_viewstart") && !virtualPath.Contains("_Layout"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("@{{ Layout = \"{0}\"; }}", LayoutPath));
        }
        writer.Write(view);
        writer.Flush();
        ourStream.Position = 0;
        return ourStream;
    }
}
```

Of course you can take care of `LayoutPath` variable and pass it from your VirtualPathProvider depending on your plugin `_Layout`.